# Apply function on specific columns in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a csv file

this file contains data as below –

```
category_list,Automotive & Sports,Blanks,Cleantech / Semiconductors,Entertainment,Health,Manufacturing,"News, Search and Messaging",Others,"Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising"
,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3D,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
3D Printing,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
3D Technology,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Accounting,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Active Lifestyle,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
Ad Targeting,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
Advanced Materials,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Adventure Travel,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

On loading it into mapping data frame ...

```
mapping <- read.csv(file="mapping.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
```

data looks as below (as expected)-
 [image]

I am trying to create a new column in this file, which will have the column name which has a 1 against a particular row. For example, for 3D row, the additional column should get the value of “Manufacturing”.
There can be only one "1" against each row.

When I run this command –

```
mapping$sector_names <- lapply(apply(mapping[2:9], 1, function(x) which(x=="1")),names)
```

its populating the sector names column correctly. As shown below –

[image]

The problem is that when I use the apply function against columns 2 thru 10, its not working, getting values NULL in sector_names in this case –

```
mapping$sector_names <- lapply(apply(mapping[2:10], 1, function(x) which(x=="1")),names)
```

[image]

The strange thing is that when I use the apply function against, columns 3 thru 10, it works fine…

[image]

In short – the question is that when I apply the “Apply” function across columns 2 thru 10, its not working, but any other combination (2 thru 9 or 3 thru 10 etc.) works.

The problem is that the apply function returns column name along with the column number when I use 2 thru 9 but only returns column number when I use 2 thru 10

Ex : - output of 
`apply(mapping[2:9], 1, function(x) which(x=="1"))`
is like this for each row…

```
[[2]]
Blanks 
     8
```

Whereas for `apply(mapping[2:10], 1, function(x) which(x=="1"))` 
is like this for each row…

```
[[1]] 2
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Can you use `dput()` to share data? Also, try the following: `sapply(1:nrow(dt), function(z) return(colnames(dt)[which(dt[z,] == 1)]))` where `dt` is your `data.frame`

Comment: Here's another way: since only one value can be 1, you could use `sapply(1:nrow(dt), function(z) return(colnames(dt)[dt[z,-1] ]))`. This does not call for using `which` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If `a` is the result of the `apply` in the question then just index the column names by it:

```
mapping$sector_names <- names(mapping)[-1][a]
```

**2)** Alternately define `mapping1` to be the matrix which is the 0-1 part of `mapping` (i.e. all but first column) and `nc1` to be its number of columns.  Multiplying that matrix by the vector 1, 2, 3, ... will give a vector of column indexes of the 1's.  Index the column names of `mappping1` by that index vector.  This involves no instances of `apply` commands.

```
mapping1 <- as.matrix(mapping[-1])
nc1 <- ncol(mapping1)
mapping$sector_names <- colnames(mapping1)[mapping1 %*% seq_len(nc1)]
```

This gives:

```
> mapping$sector
[1] "Blanks"                                 
[2] "Manufacturing"                          
[3] "Manufacturing"                          
[4] "Manufacturing"                          
[5] "Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising"
[6] "Health"                                 
[7] "Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising"
[8] "Manufacturing"                          
[9] "Automotive & Sports"
```

Comment: Maybe give him an explanation to solve the, as it seems for you, trivial question. Rather than: "here is the solution".

Comment: Agreed. But *them :)

Comment: The first option is definitely what i used. I also figured out that gather function (from tidyr) would have been able to help me here...